# Getting a number of arrays from an array list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Hi I am using Mathematica 5.2. Suppose I have an array list like

```
    In[2]:=lst=Tuples[{0,1},4]

    Out[2]={{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,1},
            {0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1},{0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1},
            {1,0,0,0},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0},{1,0,1,1},
            {1,1,0,0},{1,1,0,1},{1,1,1,0},{1,1,1,1}}
```

Now I want to get 16 arrays from the above array like st1={0,0,0,0}; st2={0,0,0,1}, st3={0,0,1,0}...
How can I get these array lists using a loop. Because if the no. of elements of the above array named lst become larger then it will not be a wise decision to take each of the element of the array lst separately and give their name separately. I tried this like the following way but it is not working...

```
Do[st[i]=lst[[i]],{i,1,16}]
```

Plz some body help me in this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *N* ways of doing this, though like [belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862486/getting-a-number-of-arrays-from-an-array-list/4865023#4865023) I have my doubts about your approach. Nonetheless, the easiest way I've found to manage things like this is to use what Mathematica calls ["pure functions"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html), like so:

```
In[1]:= lst = Tuples[{0,1}, 4];

In[2]:= With[{setter = (st[#1] = #2) &},
           Do[setter[i, lst[[i]]], {i, Length@lst}]];
```

Doing it this way, the evaluation rules for special do just what you want. However, I'd approach this without a loop at all, just using a single definition:

```
In[3]:= ClearAll[st] (* Clearing the existing definitions is important! *)

In[4]:= st[i_Integer] := lst[[i]]
```

I think if you provide more detail about what you're trying to accomplish, we'll be able to provide more useful advice.

**EDIT:** Leonid Shifrin comments that if you change the definition of `lst` after the fact, the change will also affect `st`. You can avoid this by using `With` in the way he describes:

```
With[{rhs = lst}, 
  st[i_Integer] := rhs[[i]]];
```

I don't know which will be more useful given what you're trying to do, but it's an important point either way.

Comment: I still fail to see what's wrong with the OP's original code with a simple Do loop. Also, I think OP should be aware that the two solutions you gave are not entirely equivalent. While the latter may be more elegant indeed, it introduces implicit dependence on the `lst` global variable, which is recomputed every time when `st` is called. This may or may not be desirable in this particular case, but generally I find the practice of such implicit dependencies rather fragile. A modification of your solution like `With[{lst = lst},st[i_Integer]:=lst[[i]]]` could perhaps serve him better?

Answer (score 4):

It does work, but what you create are the so-called [indexed variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html). You should access them also using the index, for example:

```
In[4]:= {st[1], st[2], st[3]}

Out[4]= {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are trying to do could be done by:

```
lst = Tuples[{0, 1}, 4];
Table[Evaluate[Symbol["lst" <> ToString[i]]] = lst[[i]], {i, Length@lst}]
```

So that

```
lst1 == {0,0,0,0}
```

But this is not a useful way to manage vars in Mathematica.

**Edit**

I'll try to show you why having vars `lst1,lst2 ..` is not useful, and is *against* the "Mathematica way".

Mathematica works better by applying functions to objects. For example, suppose you want to work with `EuclideanDistance`. You have a point {1,2,3,4} in R<sup>4</sup>, and you want to calculate the nearest point from your set to this point.

This is easily done by

```
eds = EuclideanDistance[{1, 2, 3, 4}, #] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 4]
```

And the nearest point distance is simply:

```
min = Min[eds]
```

If you want to know which point/s are the nearest ones, you can do:

```
Select[lst, EuclideanDistance[{1, 2, 3, 4}, #] == min &]
```

Now, try to do that same things with your intended `lst1,lst2 ..` asignments, and you will find it, although not impossible, very,very convoluted.

**Edit**

BTW, once you have

```
lst = Tuples[{0, 1}, 4];
```

You can access each element of the list just by typing

```
lst[[1]]
```

etc. In case you need to loop. But again, loops are NOT the Mathematica way. For example, if you want to get another list, with your elements normalized, don't loop and just do:

```
lstNorm = Norm /@ lst
```

Which is cleaner and quicker than

```
Do[st[i] = Norm@lst[[i]], {i, 1, 16}]
```

You will find that defining downvalues (like st[i]) above) is useful when solving equations, but besides that many operations that in other languages are done using arrays, in Mathematica are better carried out by using lists.

**Edit**

Answering your comment `actually I need each element of array lst to find the value of function such as f[x,y,z,k]=x-y+z+k`. Such function may be

```
 (#1 - #2 + #3 + #4) & @@@ lst
```

or

```
 (#[[1]] - #[[2]] + #[[3]] + #[[4]]) & /@ lst
```

Out:

```
{0, 1, 1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2}
```

HTH!

Comment: @rajib I'm using v8. The average Stack Overflow user is in v7 or v8. The philosophy of this is valid for all versions. EuclideanDistance[] was defined in v6 and Norm[] in version 5, but this way of working holds for any other function.

Comment: @belisarius : actually I need each element of array lst to find the value of function such as f[x,y,z,k]=x-y+z+k

Comment: @rajib @belisarius Does this contain a typo? f[x,y,z,k]=x-y+z+k

Comment: @TomD Ops! My glasses are not useful anymore :D

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
Table[
    Evaluate[
        Symbol["st" <> ToString@i]] = lst[[i]], 
            {i, 1, Length@lst}];
```

at the end of which try `Names["st*"]` to see that you now have st1 to st16 defined. You could also do this with MapIndexed, like so:

```
 MapIndexed[(Evaluate@Symbol["sts" <> ToString~Apply~#2] = #1) &, lst]
```

after which `Names["sts*"]` shows again that it has worked. Both of these can be done using a loop if this is what you (but I do not see what it buys you).

On the other hand, this way, when you want to access one of them, you need to do something like `Symbol["sts" <> ToString[4]]`. Using what you have already done or something equivalent, eg,

```
Table[
Evaluate[stg[i]] = lst[[i]],{i, 1, Length@lst}]
```

you end up with stg[1], stg[2] etc, and you can access them much more easily by eg `Table[stg[i],{i,1,Length@lst}]`

You can see what has been defined by `?stg` or in more detail by `DownValues[stg]`.

Or is it something else you want?

Leonid linked to a tutorial, which I suggest you read, by the way.

Comment: Is it applicable in mathematica 5.2 ? which version u r using ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
MapThread[Set, {Array[st, Length@lst], lst}];
```

For example:

```
{st[1], st[10], st[16]}

Out[14]= {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

Comment: ok but i want to put each of the element of the array lst into another array like a1={0,0,0,0}, a2={0,0,0,1}..., a16={1,1,1,1} using loop

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand, and I'm sorry if I misinterpreted your question. Do you require something like (rules = MapThread[Rule, {Array[A, Length@lst], lst}]) // TableForm
 and then, say?, A[16] /. rules

Comment: Actually I need to put each of the element of the array (named lst above) into another sets of array. And my question is how can I do this using a loop command (say do, for)?

Comment: @ rajib arefin I don't understand 'into another sets of array' and what are the 16 arrays you require? Perhaps someone else can clarifly? It is probably obvious, but I just can't fathom exactly what you want.